# Data table dcast column headings

Tags: r, data.table, heading, dcast

I have a data table of the form

```
ID  REGION  INCOME_BAND RESIDENCY_YEARS
1   SW  Under 5,000 10-15
2   Wales   Over 70,000 1-5
3   Center  15,000-19,999   6-9
4   SE  15,000-19,999   15-19
5   North   15,000-19,999   10-15
6   North   15,000-19,999   6-9
```

created by

```
exp = data.table(
  ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
  REGION=c("SW", "Wales", "Center", "SE", "North", "North"),
  INCOME_BAND = c("Under ?5,000", "Over ?70,000", "?15,000-?19,999", "?15,000-?19,999", "?15,000-?19,999","?15,000-?19,999"),
  RESIDENCY_YEARS = c("10-15","1-5","6-9","15-19","10-15", "6-9"))
```

I would like to transform this to

[image: Example of the result of any data table manipulation]

I've managed to perform the majority of the work with dcast:

```
exp.dcast = dcast(exp,ID~REGION+INCOME_BAND+RESIDENCY_YEARS, fun=length,
  value.var=c('REGION', 'INCOME_BAND', 'RESIDENCY_YEARS'))
```

However I need some help creating sensible column headings.
Currently I have

> ["ID"
>   "REGION.1_Center_?15,000-?19,999_6-9"
>   "REGION.1_North_?15,000-?19,999_10-15"
>   "REGION.1_North_?15,000-?19,999_6-9"
>   "REGION.1_SE_?15,000-?19,999_15-19"             "REGION.1_SW_Under
>   ?5,000_10-15"                "REGION.1_Wales_Over ?70,000_1-5"
>   "INCOME_BAND.1_Center_?15,000-?19,999_6-9"
>   "INCOME_BAND.1_North_?15,000-?19,999_10-15"
>   "INCOME_BAND.1_North_?15,000-?19,999_6-9"
>   "INCOME_BAND.1_SE_?15,000-?19,999_15-19"
>   "INCOME_BAND.1_SW_Under ?5,000_10-15"
>   "INCOME_BAND.1_Wales_Over ?70,000_1-5"
>   "RESIDENCY_YEARS.1_Center_?15,000-?19,999_6-9" 
>   "RESIDENCY_YEARS.1_North_?15,000-?19,999_10-15"
>   "RESIDENCY_YEARS.1_North_?15,000-?19,999_6-9"
>   "RESIDENCY_YEARS.1_SE_?15,000-?19,999_15-19"
>   "RESIDENCY_YEARS.1_SW_Under ?5,000_10-15"
>   "RESIDENCY_YEARS.1_Wales_Over ?70,000_1-5"

And I would like the column headings to be

```
ID  SW  Wales   Center  SE  North   Under 5,000 Over 70,000 15,000-19,999   1-5 6-9 10-15   15-19
```

Could anybody advise?

Answer (score 0):

This apparently simple question is not easy to answer. So, we will go forward step-by step.

First, the OP has tried to *reshape multiple value columns simultaneously* which creates an unwanted cross product of all available combinations.

In order to treat all values in the same way, we need to `melt()` all value columns first before reshaping:

```
melt(exp, id.vars = "ID")[, dcast(.SD, ID ~ value, length)]
```

> ```
>    ID 1-5 10-15 15-19 6-9 ?15,000-?19,999 Center North Over ?70,000 SE SW Under ?5,000 Wales
> 1:  1   0     1     0   0               0      0     0            0  0  1            1     0
> 2:  2   1     0     0   0               0      0     0            1  0  0            0     1
> 3:  3   0     0     0   1               1      1     0            0  0  0            0     0
> 4:  4   0     0     1   0               1      0     0            0  1  0            0     0
> 5:  5   0     1     0   0               1      0     1            0  0  0            0     0
> 6:  6   0     0     0   1               1      0     1            0  0  0            0     0
> ```

Now, the result has 13 columns instead of 19 and the columns are named by the respective value as requested.

Unfortunately, the columns appear in the wrong order because they alphabetically ordered. There are two approaches to change the order:

#### Change order of columns after reshaping

The `setcolorder()` function reorders the columns of a `data.table` *in place*, e.g. without copying:

```
# define column order = order of values
col_order <- c("North", "Wales", "Center", "SW", "SE", "Under ?5,000", "?15,000-?19,999", "Over ?70,000", "1-5", "6-9", "10-15", "15-19")

melt(exp, id.vars = "ID")[, dcast(.SD, ID ~ value, length)][
  # reorder columns
  , setcolorder(.SD, c("ID", col_order))]
```

> ```
>    ID North Wales Center SW SE Under ?5,000 ?15,000-?19,999 Over ?70,000 1-5 6-9 10-15 15-19
> 1:  1     0     0      0  1  0            1               0            0   0   0     1     0
> 2:  2     0     1      0  0  0            0               0            1   1   0     0     0
> 3:  3     0     0      1  0  0            0               1            0   0   1     0     0
> 4:  4     0     0      0  0  1            0               1            0   0   0     0     1
> 5:  5     1     0      0  0  0            0               1            0   0   0     1     0
> 6:  6     1     0      0  0  0            0               1            0   0   1     0     0
> ```

Now, all `REGION` columns appear first, followed by `INCOME_BAND` and `RESIDENCY_YEARS` columns in the specified order.

#### Set factor levels before reshaping

If `value` is turned into a factor with appropriately ordered factor levels `dcast()` will use the factor levels for ordering the columns:

```
melt(exp, id.vars = "ID")[, value := factor(value, col_order)][
  , dcast(.SD, ID ~ value, length)]
```

> ```
>    ID North Wales Center SW SE Under ?5,000 ?15,000-?19,999 Over ?70,000 1-5 6-9 10-15 15-19
> 1:  1     0     0      0  1  0            1               0            0   0   0     1     0
> 2:  2     0     1      0  0  0            0               0            1   1   0     0     0
> 3:  3     0     0      1  0  0            0               1            0   0   1     0     0
> 4:  4     0     0      0  0  1            0               1            0   0   0     0     1
> 5:  5     1     0      0  0  0            0               1            0   0   0     1     0
> 6:  6     1     0      0  0  0            0               1            0   0   1     0     0
> ```

#### Set factor levels before reshaping - lazy version

If it is sufficient to have the columns grouped by `REGION`, `INCOME_BAND`, and `RESIDENCY_YEARS` then we can use a short cut to avoid specifying each value in `col_order`. The `fct_inorder()` function from the `forcats` package reorders factor levels by their first appearance in a vector:

```
melt(exp, id.vars = "ID")[, value := factor(value, col_order)][
  , dcast(.SD, ID ~ value, length)]
```

> ```
>    ID SW Wales Center SE North Under ?5,000 Over ?70,000 ?15,000-?19,999 10-15 1-5 6-9 15-19
> 1:  1  1     0      0  0     0            1            0               0     1   0   0     0
> 2:  2  0     1      0  0     0            0            1               0     0   1   0     0
> 3:  3  0     0      1  0     0            0            0               1     0   0   1     0
> 4:  4  0     0      0  1     0            0            0               1     0   0   0     1
> 5:  5  0     0      0  0     1            0            0               1     1   0   0     0
> 6:  6  0     0      0  0     1            0            0               1     0   0   1     0
> ```

This works because the output of `melt()` is ordered by `variable`:

```
melt(exp, id.vars = "ID")
```

> ```
>     ID        variable           value
>  1:  1          REGION              SW
>  2:  2          REGION           Wales
>  3:  3          REGION          Center
>  4:  4          REGION              SE
>  5:  5          REGION           North
>  6:  6          REGION           North
>  7:  1     INCOME_BAND    Under ?5,000
>  8:  2     INCOME_BAND    Over ?70,000
>  9:  3     INCOME_BAND ?15,000-?19,999
> 10:  4     INCOME_BAND ?15,000-?19,999
> 11:  5     INCOME_BAND ?15,000-?19,999
> 12:  6     INCOME_BAND ?15,000-?19,999
> 13:  1 RESIDENCY_YEARS           10-15
> 14:  2 RESIDENCY_YEARS             1-5
> 15:  3 RESIDENCY_YEARS             6-9
> 16:  4 RESIDENCY_YEARS           15-19
> 17:  5 RESIDENCY_YEARS           10-15
> 18:  6 RESIDENCY_YEARS             6-9
> ```